# Where can I ask about how to differentiate between fact and opinion?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I read the differentiations between facts and opinions, and I either have doubts about them (which is unlikely), or I misunderstand them.

Is it a matter of understanding language definitions or philosophy?

### My question is:

---

I read [here](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-fact-and-opinion.html) that facts can be proven while opinions can't, but for example if I say: "It is hot!":

> It can be proven whether I'm really hot or I'm lying by observing sweat. Then all opinions can be proven; So, there are no opinions.

It is also said that facts are universal while opinions are relative, but for example if I say "Earth is an irregularly shaped ellipsoid.":

> Some people will say it is true, while some will say it is false and instead say that earth is flat. Then all facts can't be universal; So, there are no facts.

What is wrong with my claims? Do you use other definitions?

Comment: One can feel hot without sweating. And just saying something that's opposed to a fact, doesn't remove the fact. Claiming 1+0=2 doesn't collapse the entire mathematics. It's just a wrong claim. What you've presented isn't any proof that opinions are facts or that facts are opinions. Do expect this is *the first* thing you'd get feedback on, on whichever site you ask this.

Comment: Why wasting our time by asking something **after you've already acted by yourself**? You could ask before acting, wait for reply, and act upon it, but it feels like you already know the answer anyway.

Answer (score 11):

As you seem to have [asked this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92441/opinion-vs-fact) on Philosophy.SE already and it's

1. Been answered by multiple people
2. Been through the first answers and close vote queue, and is currently open
3. Currently has a positive score

We can conclude it's fairly likely to be on-topic for that site.

If, however you're asking about whether something is true that you've read in a notable publication, such as a newspaper then [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be the right place.